# Inno Setup message list somewhere?

Tags: windows, inno-setup

Is there an official list of Inno Setup messages like "WinVersionTooLowError" somewhere? I need to change the "This will install AppName on your computer" but don't know how. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default language file should have a complete list, you can view the online CVS version [here](http://cvs.jrsoftware.org/view/issrc/Files/Default.isl?view=markup).

The translation download page contains this note:

> Starting with version 5.1.0, the Inno Setup compiler will accept a
>   translation even if it's missing messages (it will use the default
>   English messages to replace them) or contains unknown messages.

so you should be able to create a custom English language file that only changes a couple of strings if that is what you want, but it is also possible to [override the strings without using language files](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_messagessection.htm).

You might also want to take a look at [Inno Setup Easy Translator](http://www.freewebs.com/valarry/downloads.htm)

Comment: Thanks... who would've thought that "Default.isl" was an English language file with all messages. LOL!